# How to use site template in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a site template called test1.stp. I have create a new web application and when creating a site collection, it is not showing the option for 'Custom tab' to select the template in web application in sharepoint 2007.

But it is available in sharepoint 2010. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the template for 2007 or 2010? It seems it is the template created from SharePoint 2010 site, so it will work only on 2010 site.

Comment: :No I have created this template in sharepoint2007 only and it is for sharepoint2007, but when i go to the central administration to create site collection from the template selection. the Option for custom tab is not available.